# Formatting string " \ "

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I need to add a `\` symbol to a string.

I can't find the way to do that, because

```
@"\" == "\\"
```

`\` is not the correct statement.

**EDIT**

Actually I am trying to generate SQL query string which contains the `'` character. In order to SQL reads it correctly I should represent it like `\'`. So, my code is something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT somequery";
query += "\\'";
```

But when SQL try to execute this query it thinks that query contains exactly `\ \\'`.

Comment: Both sides are a string that consists of a single backslash.

Comment: It is unclear what your are trying to achieve in SQL. Can you give us an example of a resulting SQL string? The result of your example would be `"SELECT somequery\'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to escape the apostrophe (') in a SQL string literal? Replace it by two apostrophes (''). The backslash applies to C#, not to SQL.

```
"WHERE text = 'don''t'"
```

**EDIT**:

May be you are looking for:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE text = '" + input.Replace("'","''") + "'";
```

But consider using SQL parameters in this case, instead of using string operations.

---

The backslash needs no escaping in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE text = '\'
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s unclear what you are trying to do, since both `"\\"` and `@"\"` are indeed the correct ways to do this (pick your poison).

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the other answers. When trying to set a value to a string, it is expected of common characters.  Certain others in the ASCII chart can not be directly typed, such as a tab key, enter, line feed, and many more.  The list of such characters as [provided here (same as provided by Gabriel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) need to be so escaped.  If you are not going to be using special escape characters, you can bypass the need to "escape" them by leading the string with an "@" which means put exactly what I have here...

Ex:

```
string MyString = @"C:\SomePath\Anything\else\File.txt";
```

is the same as

```
string MyString = "C:\\SomePath\\Anything\\else\\File.txt";
```

If you do NOT use the leading "@", the first time a "\" is encountered signifies the next character is the key representing what you want...  In the case of "\", the first turns on the "escape" mechanism, and the second is the actual character you want.

For things like Enter key and line feed, you'll commonly see these as

```
string MyMsg = "This is a sample \r\nMessage that\r\nwill span 3 lines.";
and appear as 
This is a sample
Message that
will span 3 lines.
```

You can even build strings using different types, such as

```
string MyTest = @"C:\SomePath\" + AnySubPathVariable + "\\NewFile.txt";
```

so, if "AnySubPathVariable was equal to "testing", the resulting string would become

```
C:\SomePath\testing\newfile.txt
```

Hopefully this greatly clarifies what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your character:

```
string str = "\\";             //gives \ if you use it in a label
```

[Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) for a list of character to escape in string

Can you post full example of what you need if that's not enough?